# show different product price using observer

Tags: product, price

on product detail page i want to show price other than original price via observer.

Say product with price 100 will show price as 120 or 110

which observer should i use to do same

I found product price comes from catalog/product/price.phtml

is there any way in admin > catalog > category > custom deign

to call my custom price.html for specifi category

something like below

```
<reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view_mour.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Update code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mour_Customgroup>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mour_Customgroup>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <events>
         <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <setadiscountprice>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>changeprice</method>
                </setadiscountprice>
            </observers>
          <catalog_product_load_after>
    </events>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

and observer.php

```
<?php
class Mour_Customgroup_Model_Observer
{

    public function changeprice(Varien_Event_Observer $event) {
    if($_GET['id']){
        $pricetoadd=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_GET['id'])->getPrice(); // error comes after adding this line

        $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
        $customprice = $originalprice+$pricetoadd;
        $product->setPrice($customprice);
    }
   }
}
```

i am trying to add price of product (id from get parameter) to product price

if i remove this line : $pricetoadd=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_GET['id'])->getPrice();

it works fine

Comment: you can use the checkout_cart_save_after or checkout_cart_product_add_after event. you want to change this for all products or for only particular products

Comment: no i want to show different price on product detail pages only not in cart

Comment: you want the same price to be added to cart also

Comment: yeah i am able to do that via observer ,just need to show different price on product detail page via observer'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use catalog_product_load_after event to change the product price in view page.

```
  <catalog_product_load_after>
            <observers>
                <custom_checkout_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Custom_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>loadaftercatalog</method>
                </custom_checkout_observer>
            </observers>
    </catalog_product_load_after>

public function loadaftercatalog($event) {
    $product = $event->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $originalprice = $product->getPrice();
    $customprice = $originalprice+20;
    $product->setPrice($customprice);
   }

}
```

Comment: getting same price nothing adds

Comment: I tried this, it works good for me. Please clear cache and check and check you can call the coreect observer file

Comment: see i update my code according to you, cleared cache still not working

Comment: hii after adding your code i get error maximum nesting level of 200 exceeded why so ??..

Comment: check the product price before set new price

Comment: can u please check and update my code

Comment: I have doubled checked in my local, it's working good. Please check, with your extensions if you installed any other

Comment: no please check my updated code what i did is
getting price of product from id in get parameter and adding this to product price

Comment: it is updating in admin area too. please check